# What are the advantages of using colon for commands instead of semicolon?

Tags: key-bindings, history-of

Vi very successfully minimises finger travel and speed with command mode.

Swapping <kbd>;</kbd> and <kbd>:</kbd> seems to save a lot of extra shift keystrokes for commands which are used more freqently than repititions of letter searches, but there are disadvantages to using a non standard key layout.

What are the advantages of <kbd>:</kbd> for commands? Compared to the effiency and elegance of Vi overall I feel like there must be some logic I'm missing.

Answer (score 11):

You know the [story](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/why-vim-uses-hjkl-as-arrow-keys/) behind the <kbd>h</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> keys in Vi?  Well, <kbd>:</kbd> was [unshifted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADM-3A#/media/File:KB_Terminal_ADM3A.svg) on [Vi author](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_Joy)'s [ADM-3A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADM-3A) terminal.

No idea if that's the real explanation in this particular case, but it seems at least as plausible as the <kbd>h</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> story.

Comment: +1 This definitely seems plausible. In ADM-3A, `;` is on the home row and `:` is on the top row. So if this is the reason, it could be argued even with the `shift`, that the new layout is an improvement!

Comment: Cool story about the arrows. They reused those keys for Apple IIc "console" and many video games too...